# Regex: Consume anything before a word (which might not appear)

Tags: regex

I work in an environment where I am only allowed to use Regex for string manipulation, and I need to consume a string from start until a certain keyword appears in that string. But sometimes that keyword might not appear at all - the regex needs to take this into account, meaning the keyword appearance is optional and if it doesn't appear I want to consume the full string to the end.

The keyword is **dontconsumeafterthis**

Example with the keyword:

> this is a string containing the keyword dontconsumeafterthis this part
>   should not be consumed

Required output:

> this is a string containing the keyword

Example without the keyword:

> this is another string without the keyword whatever etc. pp.

Required output:

> this is another string without the keyword whatever etc. pp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should solve it (works for me in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)):

```
(.*?)(?=dontconsumeafterthis)|(.*)
```

Explanation: There are 2 options, the last one takes the entire string if the first does not match, but the first matches only if it hits `dontconsumeafterthis` and then excludes that from the capture by using the `?=` operator - also, please note the `*?` (lazy evaluation), which takes multiple occurrences of the `dontconsumeafterthis` into account).

Comment: I got it working now - this works for me `code((.*)(?=dontconsumeafterthis)|(.*)(?!dontconsumeafterthis))` I actually don't really understand the logic why this works but as your solution pointed me into the right direction I give you the credits - thanks!

Comment: My solution wasn't working for you? Could you please clarify why not?

Comment: no idea - since this is a product from a vendor which is delivered as a black box I cannot simply verify which regex engine they use below the surface -anyway: your solution helped me to get to a working regex so thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm just puzzled as to why it doesn't. Please note also, that without lazy evaluation you aren't taking multiple occurrences into account. As for your version, option 1 only succeeds if your "magic string" is present, and option 2 only succeeds if your "magic string" isn't there, which is why it is working for you, as option 1 has "higher priority" than option 2.

Comment: Now it's getting clearer for me! So in option one it is consuming all characters until it hits the magic string. If that magic string is not present, option 1 is not evalutated to "true" and it tries option 2 which must always be "true" since it is the exact opposite logic of option 1 - with option 2 it consumes all characters from start till end - makes sense now!

Comment: Exactly. :) Which is why `(?!magicstring)` shouldn't be needed either, because then option 1 should match.

Answer (score 1):

Regex of `/.*?(dontconsumeafterthis.*)/g` should work for you.

A solution in javascript would look something like this:

```
var stringStart = "this is a string continaing the keyword dontconsumeafterthis this part should not be consumed";
var stringEnd = stringStart.replace(/.*?(dontconsumeafterthis.*)/g, "$1");
console.log(stringEnd);
```

And it'd output:

`dontconsumeafterthis this part should not be consumed`

**Notice**:

As Johny Skovdal wrote in the comments of your OP, why do you need to do this with regex? Could you perhaps do a simple string search, and substring if a match was found instead?

Javascript solution of that:

```
var stringStart = "this is a string continaing the keyword dontconsumeafterthis this part should not be consumed";
var stringFind = stringStart.indexOf("dontconsumeafterthis");
var stringEnd = (stringFind > -1 ? stringStart.substr(stringFind) : "");
console.log(stringEnd);
​
```

(same output as before)

Comment: The output should be `this is a string containing the keyword` not `dontconsumeafterthis this part should not be consumed`

Comment: I need to use a regex - cannot create my own java or script to solve this issue. Otherwise this solution would be perfect. If I use (.*?)dontconsumeafterthis.* it reads everything before the dontconsumeafterthis keyword which is fine. But if I take a string example where the dontconsumeafterthis keyword does not appear, that regex doesn't match as it is expecting this keyword

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language/environment but the general idea is to match the keyword and everything after it and replace it with nothing, if the keyword isn't matched nothing is replaced i.e: `s/keyword.*//`

```
$ cat file
this is a string continaing the keyword dontconsumeafterthis this part should not be consumed

this is another string without the keyword whatever etc. pp.6    

$ sed 's/dontconsumeafterthis.*//' file
this is a string continaing the keyword 

this is another string without the keyword whatever etc. pp.6
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately I'm depending on the environment which is a software solution that provides only an interface where I can define a regex that will be used - I cannot use my own scripts, sed, java, etc. Only a regex can be utilized...